# Angular2 Document - the meaning of "blocking and tackling"?

Tags: javascript, angular

While reading angular2 online document, I have found an unfamiliar word - "blocking and tackling" from ADVANCED - Angular Module chapter
(https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html).
...
"Most of this is familiar blocking and tackling."
...

What is the exact meaning of "blocking and tackling"?
Is that some kind of sports idioms? Then what's that mean for this context??
Please, anyone who knows the meaning help me!

Comment: For instance, using Google to search for "blocking and tackling" would be a form of "blocking and tackling". It immediately returns: "The basic, fundamental skills, tasks, or roles necessary to the function of something."

Comment: I thought there is some special meaning for this context. However, now I can understand that it still means "a basic programming technique". Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a sports metaphor used in an English expression.  It means it's basic skills - not glamorous but important:

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blocking_and_tackling

http://shoptalkmarketing.blogspot.ca/2008/10/blocking-and-tackling-mother-of-all.html